# How to Create fall effect in Xcode ArKit

Tags: xcode, arkit

I m trying to create an effect that dice thrown by hand when I tapped to screen or shake. in my reference code there is rotation effect so that dice faces changes randomly. Im trying to make this code while dice is rotating it must be fall. I mean it will fall from a predefined  coordinate y to  coordinate y 0. Any idea will be apriciated.

```
   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first{
        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: sceneView)
        let results = sceneView.hitTest(touchLocation, types: .existingPlaneUsingExtent)
        if let hitResult = results.first{
            let diceScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/diceCollada.scn")!
            if let diceNode = diceScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Dice", recursively: false){


                diceNode.position = SCNVector3(
                   hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.x,
                    hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.y + diceNode.boundingSphere.radius,
                    hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z)



                let randomX = Float(arc4random_uniform(4) + 1) * (Float.pi/2)
                let randomZ = Float(arc4random_uniform(4) + 1) * (Float.pi/2)

                diceNode.runAction(
                    SCNAction.rotateBy(x: CGFloat(randomX * 3),
                                       y: 0,
                                       z: CGFloat(randomZ * 3),
                                       duration: 0.5)
                )
                 sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(diceNode)
            }

            print(hitResult)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Tried using physics?

Comment: To be honest. I m just newbee in IOS development. So I have no idea what you mean. Could you explain that please

Comment: There are many good tutorials about scenekit, follow them. This is what i was talking about [SCNPhysicsBody](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody). And i also started scenekit 4 months earlier. Cheers